# Is there a native api in vscode to match a document file by a glob?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a `vscode.TextDocument` and want to check if the file matches a glob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const documentFilter: vscode.DocumentFilter = {
    pattern: '**/*.md',
};
const matches = vscode.languages.match(documentFilter, document) !== 0;
```

[Glob | vscode.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4cdc975fb247bcb991e23e82204c639f209be7cb/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L1862)

Answer (score 0):

Simple usage:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

documentMatchGlob(doc: vscode.TextDocument, glob: string): boolean {
    return vscode.languages.match({ pattern: glob }, document) !== 0;
}
```