# Is there a match function for vscode GlobPattern?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For an extension I'm doing I want to match the uri.path of a newly opened file to a pair of include/exclude GlobPatterns.

I've found fileSearch() API that operates on GlobPatterns, but is overkill for this;
I already have a file-path, just want to see if it satisfies the Globs.

Is there a simple "match" function for GlobPatterns?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such match function. In my own VS Code extensions I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob. It seems to be "compatible enough" with the fileSearch() API for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in: [Is there a native api in vscode to match a document file by a glob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60938873/)

[vscode.languages.match() dances through some alternatives, then invokes glob.match(...);]

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

documentMatchGlob(doc: vscode.TextDocument, glob: string): boolean {
    return vscode.languages.match({ pattern: glob }, document) !== 0;
}
```